# sql Find the pattern and count how many times it appeared

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, postgresql-8.0

**Data Give**

```
22
22
22
22
22
36
54
40
22
22
22
22
36
22
22
54
22
22
```

**This is the column in table. Using an sql query we need to find out the pattern such as 
22   36    54    40 is first pattern then 22   36 is second and 22   54 is third pattern.**

Comment: What is your definition of a "pattern" ? is there another column in the table that will define the sequence ?

Comment: So what is it? Microsoft SQL Server or PostgreSQL? Those are two very different DBMS.

Comment: Also: what defines the sort order of those rows? Rows in a relational database are not "sorted", so if you need a specific order of rows you need a column to sort by.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear what the question is asking.

Comment: We are using redshift

Comment: It is sorted by date

Comment: @HimanshuDhingra - change your data sample accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You should use LEAD to get the value of the next row to see whether it's 22, and use that to get rid of all the extra 22s in the column. Something to this effect:

```
declare @t table (id int identity(1,1) not null, n int)
insert into @t 
select 22 union all 
select 22 union all 
select 22 union all 
select 22 union all 
select 22 union all 
select 36 union all 
select 54 union all 
select 40 union all 
select 22 union all 
select 22 union all 
select 22 union all 
select 22 union all 
select 36 union all 
select 22 union all 
select 22 union all 
select 54 union all 
select 22 union all 
select 22

select id,n from (select id,n ,lead(n) over (order by id) 
as lead_val from @t ) t where n<>22 or lead_val<>22
```

This outputs:

```
5   22
6   36
7   54
8   40
12  22
13  36
15  22
16  54
```

Comment: This is a bad solution for 2 reasons: **(1)** The patterns can't be seen in this result format. E.g. there is nothing that indicates that id 12 and id 13 belongs to the same pattern. **(2)** This result can be achieved by a much simpler code `select  i,val
from   (select  i,val
               ,lead(val) over (order by i) as lead_val
        from    mytable
        ) t
where   val<>22 
     or lead_val<>22`

Comment: Yes, that's a simpler query - I updated my answer in acknowledgment.

Answer (score 0):

**PostgreSQL**

Assuming:

- There is a column that determines the order of the elements
- All patterns start with 22

---

```
select      array_to_string(array_agg(val order by i),',')  as pattern
           ,min  (i)                                        as from_i
           ,max  (i)                                        as to_i
           ,count(*)                                        as pattern_length           

from       (select  i,val
                  ,count(case when val = 22 then 1 end) over
                   (
                        order by i
                        rows unbounded preceding
                    ) as pattern_id

            from    mytable
            ) t

 group by   pattern_id

 having     count(*)>1
;
```

---

```
+-------------+--------+------+----------------+
|   pattern   | from_i | to_i | pattern_length |
+-------------+--------+------+----------------+
| 22,36,54,40 |      5 |    8 |              4 |
| 22,36       |     12 |   13 |              2 |
| 22,54       |     15 |   16 |              2 |
+-------------+--------+------+----------------+
```